# LDAP TLS fails with error 18/80

Tags: ssl, ldap

i'm following this https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/openldap-server.html#openldap-tls tutorial to setup tls for my ldap-server.

but everytime i try:

```
dn: cn=config
add: olcTLSCACertificateFile
olcTLSCACertificateFile: /etc/ssl/certs/cacert.pem
-
add: olcTLSCertificateFile
olcTLSCertificateFile: /etc/ssl/certs/ldap01_slapd_cert.pem
-
add: olcTLSCertificateKeyFile
olcTLSCertificateKeyFile: /etc/ssl/private/ldap01_slapd_key.pem


ldapmodify -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:/// -f /etc/ssl/certinfo.ldif
```

it occurs an error error 18
but if i replace the "add" with "replace" it occurs error 80

these errors appear only if i want to edit olcTLS*
if it want to edit another attribut, everything works.

i hope you can help me,

Greeny

Answer (score 1):

Try specifying `changetype: modify` after `DN: cn=config` in your ldif.  You could also try turning up the verbosity with `-v[v..]`, that might give you a hint.

Answer (score 0):

As @Tony.P suggested, seems that you forgot the `changetype` directive. Your .ldif file should look like this:

```
dn: cn=config
changetype: modify
replace: olcTLSCACertificateFile
olcTLSCACertificateFile: /etc/ssl/certs/cacert.pem
-
replace: olcTLSCertificateFile
olcTLSCertificateFile: /etc/ssl/certs/ldap01_slapd_cert.pem
-
replace: olcTLSCertificateKeyFile
olcTLSCertificateKeyFile: /etc/ssl/private/ldap01_slapd_key.pem
```

Then you can try to upload your configuration normally with:

```
ldapmodify -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:/// -f /etc/ssl/certinfo.ldif
```